# Galois groups as group schemes : a remark of Grothendieck to Serre

Tags: nt.number-theory

Towards the end of his letter to Serre dated Oct. 30, 1964 Grothendieck writes:

"For the last three weeks I have been getting very excited about the interpretation of Galois and fundamental groups of all kinds in terms of algebraic groups over number fields, especially over $\mathbb{Q}$, and even in terms of group schemes over the integers. I have convinced myself that these groups, together with the general motivic yoga, are the key to a good understanding of a transcendence conjecture linked to various cohomology lattices (integral cohomology, Hodge-de Rham cohomology), the relations between the latter and the Hodge and Tate conjectures, and a better understanding of "non-commutative" class field theory, which would realize Kronecker's "Jugendtraum", and of a functional equation for L-functions over $\mathbb{Q}$." [From Grothendieck-Serre Correspondence, p. 221, English translation]

Q.1 : Has there been a realization of Galois groups of number fields as group schemes over the integers?

Q.2 : What might Grothendieck have had in mind when he wrote that it'd lead to a better understanding of non-commutative class field theory (which is primarily pursued  under the rubric of Langlands program these days?)